# Fetch stored procedure result as JSON

Tags: python, json, sql-server, pyodbc

My code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("EXEC prcFetch")  # Fetching Json data from database via stored procedure
res = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()
print(res)                      # type(res) is list
```

Stored procedure:

```sql
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE prcFetch AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM JsonData 
    FOR JSON PATH
END
```

Output:

```
[('[{"Name":"abc","Age":"25","Gender":"M"}]',)]
```

I tried to deserialize the above output.

```
print(json.loads(res))
```

Error:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Answer (score 2):

@Martijn Pieters's answer in correct but SQL Server splits the result of `FOR JSON` into multiple rows [if it is more than 8000 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#output-of-the-for-json-clause). To get all rows as JSON in one row, try this in your stored procedure:

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE prcFetch AS
    BEGIN
     
     DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max) = (SELECT * FROM JsonData FOR JSON AUTO);
        
     SELECT @result;

    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You fetched *all* rows, by using [`cursor.fetchall()`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchall)

```
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

For a stored procedure, that's just a single row, with one column. The result is a list of rows with one element, and that one element is a tuple with a single column, with your JSON.

Don't use `cursor.fetchall()`, use [`cursor.fetchval()`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchval), which returns the first column of the first row:

```
json_data = cursor.fetchval()
```

`cursor.fetchval()` is specific to the `pyodbc` library, and not part of the Python [DB-API 2.0 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). If you are using some other library, use [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) instead, and either use indexing (`json_data = cursor.fetchone()[0]`) or tuple assignment (`json_data, = cursor.fetchone()`).

Comment: cursor.fetchval() or cursor.fetchone()[0] is not working. I am not getting the entire list.

Comment: @user15069057: define 'not working'. Your question shows that the stored procedure returned the JSON strirg `'[{"Name":"abc","Age":"25","Gender":"M"}]'`, if you expected more you'll need to fix your stored procedure. That'd be the subject of a different question.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM JsonData FOR JSON PATH` returns the entire list in SQL SERVER

Comment: @user15069057: that may well be, but I don't know how SQL Server stored procedures interact with multi-row results. It could be that you can only access the first row in that case. We solved your Python problem, please ask a _new_ question about your SQL Server SP problem.

Comment: @user15069057: also, presumably you don't *want* separate rows, but instead want **one JSON document** with all the rows.

Comment: yeah, I need all the records in one JSON document. U know how to do it?